# Probable prime tests for generalized repunit numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, primality-test

Can you provide proofs or counterexamples for the following two claims:

*First claim*

> Let $P_m(x)=2^{-m}\cdot((x-\sqrt{x^2-4})^m+(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})^m)$ . 
>   Let $M_p(a)= \frac{a^p-1}{a-1} $ where $a$ is a natural number greater than one and $p$ is an odd prime number . Let $c$ be a natural number greater than two such that $\left(\frac{c-2}{M_p(a)}\right)=-1$ and $\left(\frac{c+2}{M_p(a)}\right)=1$ where $\left(\frac{}{}\right)$ denotes Jacobi symbol. Let $S_i=P_a(S_{i-1})$ with $S_0 =P_{a}(c)$. Then , if $M_p(a)$ is prime then $S_{p-1} \equiv P_{a-2}(c) \pmod{M_p(a)}$ .

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtjsEKwjAQRO_9itpD2ZiUkip4iPsJ_QUhjZEG2yYkRenfu6Uogl4G5rEzsxrlSWUBj6Qtgr6ESrIaNKnKDB5U9uzdYGEH9-gna-42gqka0TLESuZlmX9xvnHJhOGc8gmbffCD6W23pN4-QAspTN2s1XNE-S4nc0YaFglbf4U_oUQh6lZ0yXF9zd0g4U89PbYNiBDdNEMRou90Nyw5-dEWH278GHxyMyGmXrByTaY=&lang=gp) .

*Second claim*

> Let $P_m(x)=2^{-m}\cdot((x-\sqrt{x^2-4})^m+(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})^m)$ . 
>   Let $N_p(b)= \frac{b^p+1}{b+1} $ where $b$ is a natural number greater than one and $p$ is an odd prime number . Let $c$ be a natural number greater than two such that $\left(\frac{c-2}{N_p(b)}\right)=-1$ and $\left(\frac{c+2}{N_p(b)}\right)=1$ where $\left(\frac{}{}\right)$ denotes Jacobi symbol. Let $S_i=P_b(S_{i-1})$ with $S_0 =P_{b}(c)$. Then , if $N_p(b)$ is prime then $S_{p-1} \equiv P_{b+2}(c) \pmod{N_p(b)}$

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtjk0KwjAQRvc5Re2iTEyKpAou4hzBHkEwMdLSn4SkKL29U4oi6Gbge8z3ZgwelGYB1VGzGsFcglB8B4amZhb3mj2btnewgS760dnORbBlJWuOWKqsKLIvLlauuLRCUD9htQ2-t40zc2rcA4xU0u6qRT1FVG85hROGUsmEZ3-DP6VEJXJr2hS4vNbeIeGPnh5YD8gQ23GCPERvrqafM8qDyz_c-iH41E6EuH4BrTpNpA==&lang=gp) .

I have verified these claims for many random values from [this list](http://www.primenumbers.net/Henri/us/MersFermus.htm) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two claims are true.

*Proof for the first claim* :

It can be proven by induction on $i$ that
$$S_i=2^{-a^{i+1}}(s^{a^{i+1}}+t^{a^{i+1}})\tag1$$
where $s:=c-\sqrt{c^2-4},t:=c+\sqrt{c^2-4}$.$\ \ $ (The proof can be seen in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2954969/78967).)

Let $N:=M_p(a)=\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}$. Then, from $(1)$, we get, using $2(c\pm\sqrt{c^2-4})=(\sqrt{c+2}\pm\sqrt{c-2})^2$,
$$\begin{align}S_{p-1}&=2^{-(a-1)N-1}(s^{(a-1)N+1}+t^{(a-1)N+1})
\\\\&=2^{-(a-1)N-1}(s\cdot s^{(a-1)N}+t\cdot t^{(a-1)N})
\\\\&=2^{-2(a-1)N-1}\bigg(s((\sqrt{c+2}-\sqrt{c-2})^{N})^{2(a-1)}
\\&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad+t((\sqrt{c+2}+\sqrt{c-2})^{N})^{2(a-1)}\bigg)\tag2\end{align}$$

Here, we have, by the binomial theorem,
$$\begin{align}&(\sqrt{c+2}\pm\sqrt{c-2})^{N}
\\\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{N}\binom Nk(\sqrt{c+2})^{N-k}(\pm\sqrt{c-2})^k
\\\\&=\sqrt{c+2}\sum_{j=0}^{(N-1)/2}\binom{N}{2j}(c+2)^{(N-2j-1)/2}(c-2)^{j}
\\&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \pm\sqrt{c-2}\sum_{j=1}^{(N+1)/2}\binom{N}{2j-1}(c+2)^{(N-2j+1)/2}(c-2)^{j-1}\end{align}$$

So, there are integers $C,D$ such that 
$$(\sqrt{c+2}\pm\sqrt{c-2})^{N}=C\sqrt{c+2}\pm D\sqrt{c-2}\tag3$$
where 
$$C=\sum_{j=0}^{(N-1)/2}\binom{N}{2j}(c+2)^{(N-2j-1)/2}(c-2)^{j}\equiv \left(\frac{c+2}{N}\right)\equiv 1\pmod N\tag4$$
and
$$D=\sum_{j=1}^{(N+1)/2}\binom{N}{2j-1}(c+2)^{(N-2j+1)/2}(c-2)^{j-1}\equiv \left(\frac{c-2}{N}\right)\equiv -1\pmod N\tag5$$

It follows from $(2)(3)(4)(5)$ that
$$\begin{align}2^{(2a-2)(N-1)}\cdot S_{p-1}&=2^{-2a+1}\bigg(s((\sqrt{c+2}-\sqrt{c-2})^{N})^{2(a-1)}
\\&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad+t((\sqrt{c+2}+\sqrt{c-2})^{N})^{2(a-1)}\bigg)
\\\\&=2^{-2a+1}\bigg(s(C\sqrt{c+2}- D\sqrt{c-2})^{2(a-1)}
\\&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad+t(C\sqrt{c+2}+ D\sqrt{c-2})^{2(a-1)}\bigg)
\\\\&\equiv 2^{-2a+1}\bigg(s(\sqrt{c+2}+\sqrt{c-2})^{2(a-1)}
\\&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad+t(\sqrt{c+2}-\sqrt{c-2})^{2(a-1)}\bigg)\pmod N
\\\\&= 2^{-2a+1}(s\cdot 2^{a-1}t^{a-1}+t\cdot 2^{a-1}s^{a-1})
\\\\&= 2^{-(a-2)}(s^{a-2}+t^{a-2})
\\\\&=P_{a-2}(c)\end{align}$$
It follows from $2^{N-1}\equiv 1\pmod N$ that
$$S_{p-1}\equiv P_{a-2}(c)\pmod{M_p(a)}\quad\blacksquare$$

---

*Proof for the second claim* :

Let $N:=N_p(b)= \frac{b^p+1}{b+1}$. Then, from $(1)$, we get, similarly as above,
$$\begin{align}2^{2(b+1)(N-1)}\cdot S_{p-1}&=2^{(b+1)N-2b-1}(s^{(b+1)N-1}+t^{(b+1)N-1})
\\\\&=2^{-2b-3}\bigg(t\cdot ((\sqrt{c+2}-\sqrt{c-2})^N)^{2(b+1)}
\\&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad +s\cdot ((\sqrt{c+2}+\sqrt{c-2})^N)^{2(b+1)}\bigg)
\\\\&=2^{-2b-3}\bigg(t\cdot (C\sqrt{c+2}-D\sqrt{c-2})^{2(b+1)}
\\&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad +s\cdot (C\sqrt{c+2}+D\sqrt{c-2})^{2(b+1)}\bigg)
\\\\&\equiv 2^{-2b-3}\bigg(t\cdot (\sqrt{c+2}+\sqrt{c-2})^{2(b+1)}
\\&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad +s\cdot (\sqrt{c+2}-\sqrt{c-2})^{2(b+1)}\bigg)\pmod N
\\\\&=2^{-2b-3}(t\cdot 2^{b+1}t^{b+1}+s\cdot 2^{b+1}s^{b+1})
\\\\&=2^{-(b+2)}(s^{b+2}+t^{b+2})
\\\\&=P_{b+2}(c)
\end{align}$$
from which
$$S_{p-1}\equiv P_{b+2}(c)\pmod{N_p(b)}$$
follows.$\quad\blacksquare$